# Measuring the network usage of a C++ websocket

Tags: python, c++, networking, websocket, bandwidth

I am trying to measure the network usage of a websocket client getting data from an external server, and am confused by the results I am seeing.

I am using a Linux dedicated server hosted by a provider in the US.  A C++ process connects to the server over the internet, opens a connection and receives data.  On each message received, the process pushes the messages onto an internal UDP socket, for another process to consume. That other process stores the data in a log file using fwrite.

I am using `websocketpp` for the websocket. The streamed data comes in json format.

Here is my problem.  When I try to measure the network usage in real-time using `/sys/class/net/statistics`, I measure roughly 1 MB/s on `rx_bytes`.  Lower down this post is my python script to do that.

However, when I post-process the log file using a C++ program at the end of the day, I measure a much higher bandwidth at peak traffic (like 500 MB/s).  Lower down this post is my C++ reader code.

Could you please help me understand what I am missing?
Thanks!

python program to measure bandwidth in real-time:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime


def get_bytes(t, iface='enp1s0f0'):
    with open('/sys/class/net/' + iface + '/statistics/' + t + '_bytes', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read();
        return int(data)

while(True):
    tx1 = get_bytes('tx')
    rx1 = get_bytes('rx')

    time.sleep(1)

    tx2 = get_bytes('tx')
    rx2 = get_bytes('rx')

    tx_speed = round((tx2 - tx1)/1000000.0, 4)
    rx_speed = round((rx2 - rx1)/1000000.0, 4)

    now_str = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    line = f"{now_str}\tTX: {tx_speed:>.4f} MB/s  RX: {rx_speed:>.4f} MB/s"
    print(line)

    with open("log.txt","a") as fh:
        fh.write(line)
        fh.write("\n")
```

This program prints out this kind of data:

`2022-03-15 13:27:55    TX: 0.0358 MB/s  RX: 1.3821 MB/s`

C++ program to measure bandwith offline:

```
int num_bytes_per_sec = 0;
int max_bytes_per_sec = 0;
long int max_bytes_per_sec_timestamp = 0;
long int ref_time = 0;
char msg_data[30000];

while (!feof(fp))
    {
        // read next message size
        int memsz;
        read = fread (&memsz, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        if (read == 0)
        {
            if (ferror(fp))
                printf("error reading. %d\n", read);
            break;
        }
        assert(read == 1);

        // read the message
        read = fread (msg_data, sizeof(char), memsz, fp);
        assert(read = memsz);

        // the foo method extracts the event time from the message, in ms
        time_t event_time = 0;
        foo (msg_data, &event_time);

        // track bandwidth
        if (ref_time == 0 || event_time - ref_time > 1000)
        {
            if (num_bytes_per_sec > max_bytes_per_sec)
            {
                max_bytes_per_sec = num_bytes_per_sec;
                max_bytes_per_sec_timestamp = event_time;
            }
            num_bytes_per_sec = 0;
            ref_time = event_time;
        } 
        num_bytes_per_sec += sizeof(char) * strlen(msg_data);
}
```

Printing `max_bytes_per_sec` at the end of the program returns `547987980`.

Comment: `assert(read = memsz);` is a bug, and msg_data is not null-terminated so please make sure your parsing function knows this.

How much troubleshooting have you done yourself? Does msg_data contain the corrcet information? Does Event_time contain the correct information?

Comment: Thanks, @user253751.  Indeed, that `assert` contained a bug.  Also, you're right the string is not null-terminated and that was another bug.  I switched to this `num_bytes_per_sec += sizeof(char) * memsz` and the result makes much more sense (10 MB).

Comment: The fact that it "makes sense" doesn't mean it's actually right. Why do you add `sizeof(char) * memsz`? What is the purpose of that line?